# How can I iterate over a collection and change values with LINQ extension methods?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

Lets say I have a collection of Messages which has the properties "UserID" (int) and "Unread" (bool).

How can I use LINQ extension methods to set Unread = false, for any Message in the collection in whose UserID = 5?

So, I know I can do something like:

```
messages.Any(m => m.UserID == 5);
```

But, how do I set the Unread property of each of those with an extension method as well?

Note: I know I should not do this in production code.  I'm simply trying to learn some more LINQ-fu.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use a regular for-each iterating over the filtered collection?

Comment: @helios, no.  This isn't production code.  I'm just having fun and I was curious if I could iterate over the items using LINQ

Comment: Just for convention and general sanity sake, call it read, not Unread.  if(m.Read) is so much easier to understand than if (!m.Unread).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, this is possible using only the built-in LINQ extension methods without `ToList`.
I believe that this will perform very similarly to a regular `for` loop.  (I haven't checked)

Don't you **dare** do this in real code.

```
messages.Where(m => m.UserID == 5)
        .Aggregate(0, (m, r) => { m.Unread = false; return r + 1; });
```

As an added bonus, this will return the number of users that it modified.

Comment: Could you explain why we shouldn't do this in production code?

Answer (score 5):

`messages.Where(m => m.UserID == 5).ToList().ForEach(m => m.Unread = false);`

Then submit the changes.

Comment: `Any` returns a bool, so that's not correct- you'd probably want `Where`

Comment: Any is not correct because it checks if there is at least one message with UserID 5 in the collection and returns true or false. You need to use Where instead of any. Also be aware of the fact that creating a list can be expensive when the collection is really big. See also my answer which suggests MoreLinq's extension method ForEach.

Comment: Select isn't right - that's going to return an `IEnumerable<bool>`. You mean `Where`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, just not awake yet.  Fixed it now.

Answer (score 4):

Standard LINQ extension methods doesn't include side effects aimed methods. However you can either implement it yourself or use from [Reactive Extensions for .NET (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) like this:

```
messages.Where(m => m.UserID == 5).Run(m => m.Unread = false);
```

Answer (score 4):

As there is no explicit extension method that does a `ForEach`, you are stuck with either using a secondary library, or writing the foreach statement on your own.

```
foreach (Message msg in messages.Where(m => m.UserID == 5))
{
    msg.Unread = false;
}
```

If you really want to use a Linq statement to accomplish this, create a copy the collection using the `ToList()` method, accessing the `ForEach()` method of the `List` type:

```
messages.Where(m => m.UserID == 5).ToList().ForEach(m => m.Unread = false);
```

or place the side-effect in a `Where()` statement:

```
messages.Where(m =>
{
    if (m.UserID == 5) { m.Unread = false; return true; }
    return false;
});
```

In either case, I prefer to use the explicit `foreach` loop as it doesn't make unnecessary copies and is clearer than the `Where` hack.

Comment: Calling `Select` won't actually do anything until the result is enumerated.  You should call `.Count()` on `Select`'s return value to force the entire collection to be enumerated.  Also, your first `Select` should actually be `Where`.

Comment: Caught that immediately after posting.

Comment: The last method still won't work.  Calling `Where` won't actually do anything until its return value is enumerated.  You need to call `.Count()`.  Also, you missed a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

With LINQ you can't because LINQ is a query language/extension. There is however a project called [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), which defines an extension method called ForEach which allows you to pass an action which will be performed on every element.

So, you could do with MoreLinq:

```
messages.Where(m => m.UserID == 5).ForEach(m => m.Unread = false);
```

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi

Comment: This is not strictly true.  The reason that LINQ can't do this has nothing to do with the fact that it's a query language/extension.  (Besides the fact that LINQ can do this)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is *in the spirit* of providing a solution. On could create an extension which does both the predicate (`Where` extension) to weed out the items and the action needed upon those items.

Below is an extension named `OperateOn` which is quite easy to write:

```
public static void OperateOn<TSource>(this List<TSource> items, 
                                      Func<TSource, bool> predicate, 
                                      Action<TSource> operation)
{
    if ((items != null) && (items.Any()))
    {
        items.All (itm =>
        {
            if (predicate(itm))
                operation(itm);

            return true;
        });

    }
}
```

Here is it in action:

```
var myList = new List<Item>
                   { new Item() { UserId = 5, Name = "Alpha" },
                     new Item() { UserId = 5, Name = "Beta", UnRead = true },
                     new Item() { UserId = 6, Name = "Gamma", UnRead = false }
                   };


myList.OperateOn(itm => itm.UserId == 5, itm => itm.UnRead = true);

Console.WriteLine (string.Join(" ",
                               myList.Select (itm => string.Format("({0} : {1})",
                                                                   itm.Name,
                                                                   itm.UnRead ))));

/* Outputs this to the screen

(Alpha : True) (Beta : True) (Gamma : False)

*/
```

...

```
public class Item
{
    public bool UnRead { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do it in a Select(), remember the lambda is a shortcut for a function, so you can put as much logic in there as you want, then return the current item being enumerated.  And... why exactly wouldn't you do this in production code?

```
messages = messages
    .Select(m => 
    {
        if (m.UserId == 5) 
            m.Unread = true;
        return m;
    });
```